# Adding entire phone's contact list into application database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, contacts, android-contacts

I'm new to Android and developing an app in which I need to store entire phone's contact list into my application database on the launch of the application.

As I searched on web, all I got the answers for inserting contacts one by one in your application database. But I want to have the entire contact list into my database and then work on that contact database.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

My code snippet is in below answer comment.

Comment: do you need to store them in  local(mobile) or server? I think storing locally is the better approach!  using sqlite.

Comment: I want to store it in my app(the one that m developing using eclipse) local sqlite database. Just like WhatsApp has its own database(Just an example).

Comment: Using ContentResolver class u can get all the contact and details you can store them using SQlite

Comment: What do you mean by "adding entire phone's contact list"? Do you mean fetching all the contacts at once ?

Comment: Yes Shahzeb, storing all the contacts at once at the launch of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems no effort !! any way , you can use **ContentResolver** class . That provides list of contacts from your device contact list .Here is the code stuff for this ,

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
              String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
              if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                 Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                           null,
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                           new String[]{id}, null);
                 while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
              Log.e("TAG","Name :: "+Name);
              Log.e("TAG","Phone no :: "+phoneNo);

                 }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope you are aware how to store these contacts one by one in side **sqlite** **database** .If any query , feel free to ask

Comment: I guess this is not much different from extracting contacts one by one. I'll try this will let you know. Thanks for providing the solution. :)

Comment: Hi Jigs, i'm getting an exception "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed". Please find my code snippets in answer comment.

Comment: @user3098795 : text ur java files or give me ur mail id , so we can discuss there .

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things :

## 1. Retrive all contacts

Check for this [Android developer link](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html) :

This link contains How to :

1. Retrieving a List of Contacts
2. Retrieving Details for a Contact

### 2. Store all data to database

Use 'OrmLite' or any orm to add this data in to database.
Here is guide for [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/).

Hope It will help.